# How to check a 2D matrix is empty?

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, null

I think that all we need is

```
if (matrix.length == 0)
```

However, I saw some of them write

```
if (matrix == null || matrix.length == 0 || matrix[0].length == 0)
```

Is my version enough to check a matrix is empty or not or we need to write the above version?

Comment: Nope, the second version is better.

Comment: Try testing your version with actual different values for `matrix`.  You'll find out why quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get a `NullPointerException` if you call `matrix.length()` if matrix is null, that's why the second check is better.

Comment: Can we just write if(matrix==null)and leave out the rest of two condition? @Vucko

Comment: no, because matrix can be not null and still empty if it has no data in it.